# Expect : input password is not working

Tags: expect

```
set pass "lab"
spawn telnet 10.105.247.86
expect "Username:*"; send "lab  \r"
expect "Password:*"; send "$pass\r"
```

tried this code , but getting the error   :-

```
bash-4.1$ expect bh_crone_envset.exp
spawn telnet 10.105.247.86
Trying 10.105.247.86...
Connected to 10.105.247.86.
Escape character is '^]'.


User Access Verification

Username: lab  
Password: 
% Login invalid
```

Comment: Please try to add a better text description so that your question clearly expresses your effort and your question.

Comment: the `interact` command hands control over to the user, and you would have to program in a trigger to put control back to the script. It is effectively blocking your script. Remove it.

Comment: set pass "lab"
spawn telnet 10.105.247.86
expect "Username:*"; send "lab  \r"
expect "Password:*"; send "$pass\r"

tried this code , but getting the error   :-                                                                

bash-4.1$ expect bh_crone_envset.exp
spawn telnet 10.105.247.86
Trying 10.105.247.86...
Connected to 10.105.247.86.
Escape character is '^]'.


User Access Verification

Username: lab  
Password: 
% Login invalid

Answer (score 0):

```
send "lab  \r"
```

You're sending extra spaces after the username. And after `send "$pass\r"` you may need to `interact` or the Expect script would exit immediately.